# Dropwizard Jersey Configuration to group resources to specific rootPaths

Tags: java, rest, jersey, dropwizard

I'm working on a project with many existing API endpoints define across many resource classes. Currently we have a `urlPattern` defined as /api/* but want to add another set of resources for internal use under say /internal/* however, since we have the `urlPattern` set, these are under /api/internal/*. Is there a way to configure Dropwizard Jersey to accommodate this other than taking out the `urlPattern` and prefixing all endpoints with /api or /internal in the resource class @Path annotations?

Notes:
The `urlPattern` is defined either by `environment.jersey().setUrlPattern` or in the config yml under `server:rootPath`.

Tried this but obviously it doesn't work because the second set overwrites the first.

```
environment.jersey().setUrlPattern("/api/*");
environment.jersey().setUrlPattern("/internal/*");
```

I thought of injecting a config value on certain resources but for some reason the `@Path` annotation doesn't allow that

Example

```
@Path("/{internal-path}/"
```

Comment: or... is there a way to specify a folder or package of resources to be from the default root path outside of the configured rootPath?

like say rootPath is set to /api/* but I have a folder/package of resources that would be from /*

Comment: If you want to serve both endpoints with a single servlet, you'll have to use rootPath `/*`. If you want to separate them, perhaps you can add a second servlet to your server, one for each root path?

Comment: Yeah, I want to do the second servlet option but can't find any good documentation on this ... :(